# LoadError: cannot load such file -- ox/ox

Tags: ruby, docker-compose

after `docker compose up --build` it says `LoadError: cannot load such file -- ox/ox`. Never seen anything like ox/ox before and the www have also no clue?! Any suggestions?

Thank you!

I deleted everything and build from scratch new docker container/images etc. Right Ruby version.

Comment: I would start with a `grep -R ox/ox` in my project directory, maybe that provides clues in which direction you must search.

Comment: @ruud it shows matches in 3 Binary files
for example: Binary file ./tmp/cache/bootsnap/load-path-cache matches

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a longer stack trace if one is available? That usually hints at where it comes from.

Comment: https://github.com/ohler55/ox/issues/302

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this error on a [Danger](https://github.com/danger/danger) upgrade to version 9.1.0:

`Invalid Dangerfile file: cannot load such file -- ox/ox`

A bump from Ruby 2.4.0 to Ruby 2.7.0, and updating a transient dependency on ox to version 2.14.14 (via "bundle update danger-junit" in my case), fixed it for me.

Hope this helps someone else out.